# I want to change a parameter url to a static url

Tags: jquery, api

I have this url on my WordPress staging site for a jobs website, this is a single job listing:

```
http://razzbri.dirtandrust.com/careers/?ja-job=3061304
```

Which I want to redirect and show at this url instead so it can be shared on social media:

```
http://razzbri.dirtandrust.com/careers/3061304
```

The problem is the url is updated via jQuery GET call (this from the JS console in the browser) but isn't refreshing the browser:

```
https://apps.jobadder.com/widgets/V1/Jobs/RenderSearchForm?callback=jQuery191021154481897236577_1528749487705&key=KEYWASHEREBUTIREMOVEDIT&classificationsToExclude=&showLabels=true&optionText=&showKeywordSearch=true&autoSearch=true&showSearchButton=true&searchButtonText=Search&_=1528749487706
```

The url that's shared to social media is only, no matter what job is chosen, the parameter gets stripped away:

```
http://razzbri.dirtandrust.com/careers
```

What's the best way to fix this? I've tried using jQuery to strip the parameter when sharing the job url http://razzbri.dirtandrust.com/careers/3055937 but that still leaves the url in the url bar with the parameter which can't be copied and pasted and shared. It also doesn't get redirected properly because of the issue above (no page refresh so no redirect).

The htaccess I've tried is:

```
RewriteRule ^careers/(\d+) \?ja-job=$1 [L]
```

My last option is use the JobAdder API, do you reckon this is preferred and if so, how do I update the url so it is a page and not a url parameter?

https://developers.jobadder.com/documents

Comment: a) "the url is updated via ajax, I believe" there's your first problem, specifically, that you're really not sure what the problem is b) Do you have server side access?  If so and you're running Apache, this sounds like a job for mod_rewrite.  Google for "apache rewrite"

Comment: I'm using the JobAdder widget, which is why I'm not sure if they are using Ajax or not. However, I click on a job and the url updates without the page refreshing, so I assume ajax in this case. No?

Comment: use .htaccess to mod_rewrite

Comment: Hi @Wils how would you write that? I've tried unsuccessfully.

Comment: @NathanielFlick you can post your htaccess here.

Comment: @Wils I've updated the question with that htaccess.

Comment: To tell whether something is being done via Ajax open Chrome developer tools Network tab than the XHR sub-tab -- this will show the Ajax requests

Comment: Thanks for the info @GeorgeJempty I've looked at XHR and didn't see anything but in JS I've seen a call for jQuery data: https://apps.jobadder.com/widgets/V1/Jobs/RenderSearchForm?callback=jQuery191021154481897236577_1528749487705&key=KEYWASHEREBUTIREMOVEDIT&classificationsToExclude=&showLabels=true&optionText=&showKeywordSearch=true&autoSearch=true&showSearchButton=true&searchButtonText=Search&_=1528749487706

Comment: Everybody else has given you more than enough detail on rewriting URLs

Comment: Hi @GeorgeJempty thx

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI} !-s
RewriteRule ^careers/(.*)$ careers/index.php?jajob=$1 [L]
```

try this
Structure

```
/.htaccess
/careers/index.php
```

/careers/index.php

```
<?php echo $_REQUEST[jajob];
```